# Chrome doesn't redirect user back to Flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, deep-linking

I've a Flutter application. We need to connect to our api at: Api.domain.com but they also need to redirect back to our application without iftame.

So we use firebase: app.page.link but this doesn't send the user back to the app.

How can i send the user back to our app from mobile chrome browser without an iframe.

I thought app://app_name/deeplink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make deeplinking work on `Chrome` browsers, you will need to use `Intent` method, here you can find an example of how to do it:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/multidevice/android/intents/